script issue to fetch linux memory detail
Below script is not working on linux platform and it is giving an error as per below.
Error:

sh LatestMem.sh (standard in) 1: illegal character: ^M (standard in)
1: illegal character: ^M
LatestMem.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found.
LatestMem.sh: line 9: $'\r': command not found.
LatestMem.sh: line 18: syntax error: unexpected end of file –

Script:
#! /bin/bash

mem_tot=$(free -m|grep Mem|awk '{print $2}')

mem_avlbl=$(free -m|grep Mem|awk '{print $7}')

avlbl_per=$(echo "(""$mem_avlbl"" / ""$mem_tot"")\*100" | bc -l | awk '{printf("%.0f\\n",$1)}')

#echo $mem_tot

#echo $mem_avlbl

#echo $avlbl_per

if \[ "$avlbl_per" -lt "10" \]

then

echo "Memory High Usage, Memory_Tot=$mem_tot, Memory_Avlbl=$mem_avlbl, Mem_Avlbl_Per=$avlbl_per"

else

echo "Memory Usage Below Threshold, Memory_Tot=$mem_tot, Memory_Avlbl=$mem_avlbl, Mem_Avlbl_Per=$avlbl_per"

fi

Tried to execute the script on linux platform but getting error.
